# android: How to read intent uri extra data

Tags: android, intentfilter

I need (if it is possible) to handle an "url" like this (in an email I need to open my app ("wics")):

```
http://wics/resetPassword/myemail@mydomain.ext/FOOBARTOKEN
```

I have this in my AndroidManifest.xml

```
<activity android:name=".ResetPasswordActivity">
            android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
                <data android:scheme="http"
                    android:host="wics"/>
            </intent-filter>   
</activity>
```

How can I get "myemail@mydomain.ext" and "FOOBARTOKEN" in my ResetPasswordActivity ?

I have insert this code:

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
Uri uri = (Uri)intent.getData();
```

But now ? split "uri" string and get 3td and 4th elements ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well you could do something like this.

```
<meta-data android:name="my_url" android:value="http://wics/resetPassword/myemail@mydomain.ext/FOOBARTOKEN" />
```

then get it in code.

```
ApplicationInfo appInfo = getPackageManager().getApplicationInfo(getPackageName(), PackageManager.GET_META_DATA);
Bundle bundle = appInfo.metaData;

String url = bundle.getString("my_url");
Uri uri = Uri.parse(url);
```

Then split on the "/" delimiter.

```
String[] arr =  url.split("/");
```

then all you need to do is loop over the arr and find your words.
make any sense?

Comment: please the answer as accepted .thank you. always willing to share knowledge.

Comment: thanks @Caspain. I had done simil-like your comment but I thinked that this was not the correct method to follow. Thanks again.